Vary raster transparency based on cell values in ArcGIS Pro
I am trying to achieve varying transparency for a raster layer based on cell values in ArcGIS Pro. My goal is to make cells with lower values more transparent and cells with higher values less transparent. I found an old post: Varying transparency of symbols within single layer in ArcMap on GIS Stack Exchange that discusses this for ArcMap, but the solution does not seem to apply to ArcGIS Pro.  The final result would look something like this:

Here's what I have done so far:

Reclassified Raster Values:

I used the "Reclassify" tool to reclassify my raster values from 0 to 255.

Created a Composite Raster:

I used the "Composite Bands" tool to create a multi-band raster where I included the reclassified raster in multiple bands (Band 1, Band 2, Band 3, and Band 4 as the alpha channel).

Set Alpha Channel:

In the Symbology pane, I set the alpha channel to Band 4. However, I do not see any transparency effect, and there is no "Alpha channel" checkbox in the Symbology settings.
Here is a screenshot of my Symbology settings and raster:

How can I effectively vary the transparency of my raster layer based on cell values in ArcGIS Pro?
I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2.

In the original layer's Symbology choose a color ramp of your choice.  For example, a black to white ramp called 'Continuous Color Scheme' is a good option.
After selecting the color ramp click on the color ramp and choose the format color option.  This will open the dialog as shown below.
Click on the marker the represents white and change that to No Color.  Click on the black square and change that to your color choice (it looks like you want magenta).

You can slide the No Color box closer to the center to alter the transparency to your liking.

